# For Each tuple in the Databag is executing from the try block again and again

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Here is  the code:

```
public class databag extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {
TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
BagFactory mBagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();

private DataBag result;
private String delimiterType = ": Src / dest :";
public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

    try{
        result = mBagFactory.newDefaultBag(); // change here
        result.add(input);

        getLogger().info("::::::: Entered try block ::::::::::::");

        // create indexing for source and destination . ::: (Arraylist<Object[]>)
        ConcurrentHashMap<Object, ArrayList<Integer>> srcIndexMap =  new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ConcurrentHashMap<Object, ArrayList<Integer>> destIndexMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, ArrayList<Integer>>();


        // store the rows to Arraylist(Object[]) collection by converting . 
        ArrayList<Object[]> source = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        ArrayList<Object[]> destination = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        int srcCounter = 0;
        int destCounter = 0;

    ArrayList<Integer> Sourcearray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> Destinationarray = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
for (Iterator<Tuple> iter = result.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
//some code here
}
```

I'm trying to iterate tuples in a databag using for loop, but for every tuple all the collections are reinitialized in other words its executing from the try block for each tuples.

output:

```
INFO  PigUDFpck.databag - ::::::: Entered try block ::::::::::::
PigUDFpck.databag - srcIndexMap={}
PigUDFpck.databag - inside main if loop skey=4
PigUDFpck.databag - destIndexMap.contains(skey)=false
PigUDFpck.databag - into else loop of main method
PigUDFpck.databag - ::::::: Entered try block ::::::::::::
PigUDFpck.databag - srcIndexMap={}
PigUDFpck.databag - inside main if loop skey=4
PigUDFpck.databag - destIndexMap.contains(skey)=false
PigUDFpck.databag - into else loop of main method
```

UPDATED

Pig Script

```
REGISTER /usr/local/pig/UDF/UDFBAG.jar;

sourcenew = LOAD 'hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/DVTTest/Source1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:int,Name:chararray,FirstName:chararray ,LastName:chararray,Vertical_Name:chararray ,Vertical_ID:chararray,Gender:chararray,DOB:chararray,Degree_Percentage:chararray ,Salary:chararray,StateName:chararray);

destnew = LOAD 'hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/DVTTest/Destination1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:int,Name:chararray,FirstName:chararray ,LastName:chararray,Vertical_Name:chararray ,Vertical_ID:chararray,Gender:chararray,DOB:chararray,Degree_Percentage:chararray ,Salary:chararray,StateName:chararray);

cogroupnew = COGROUP sourcenew BY ID inner, destnew BY ID inner;

diff_data = FOREACH cogroupnew GENERATE DIFF(sourcenew,destnew);

ids = FOREACH diff_data GENERATE FLATTEN($0);

id1 = DISTINCT( FOREACH ids GENERATE $0);

src = FILTER sourcenew BY ID == id1.$0;

finalsrc = FOREACH src GENERATE *, 'Source' as Source:chararray;

dest = FILTER destnew BY ID == id1.$0;

finaldest = FOREACH dest GENERATE *, 'Destination' as Destination:chararray;

final =  UNION finalsrc,finaldest ;

A = FOREACH final GENERATE PigUDFpck.databag(*);

DUMP A;
```

and the input to the UDF as follows:

```
(4,JOHN Hansel,JOHN,Hansel,Banking ,4,M,20-01-1994,78.65,345000,ArkansasSrc1,Source)

(4,JOHN Hansel,JOHN,Hansel,Banking ,4,M,20-01-1994,78.65,345000,ArkansaSrc2,Source)

(4,JOHN Hansel,JOHN,Hansel,Banking ,4,M,20-01-1994,78.65,345000,Arkansasdest1,Destination)

(4,JOHN Hansel,JOHN,Hansel,Banking ,4,M,20-01-1994,78.65,345000,Arkanssdest2,Destination)
```

Help is much appreciated.!!
Thanks in Advance..!

Answer (score 0):

Please understand PIG is a DAG generator and based on the DAG it spawns Map Reduce Jobs.

Higher level PIG constructs like LOAD , FOREACH , JOIN boils to lower level MR constructs of

```
> Load       => Mapper in MR 
> GENRERATE  => a function call in Mapper or Reduce
> JOIN       => SHUFFLE (Join in Map Reduce)
> Filter     => Filter function in Map or Reduce
```

The databag function is being called not once but multiple times as its a function call being executed in Mapper of Reducer.

For each input ROW( depending on databag UDF becomes part of mapper or reducer) the dataBag will be executed.

Please go through the EXPAIN command in pig which translates PIG script to chaing of underlying MR jobs

For a detailed understanding Please follow :

> 1. http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/pig-to-map-and-reduce/
> 2. http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/understanding-map-reduce-the-missing-guide/

Comment: Thanks @KrazyGautam I understood that it will get executed for each tuple in the databag but is it possible to segregate the tuple into two arrays and compare them for the best mach out of the source and destination arrays..?

Comment: @Vickyster Why don't you just do group by on the pig script side and recieve a tuple with databag in your UDF?

Comment: Hi @Alexey, I can group it but unfortunately I'm appending  'Source' and 'Destination' to the tuple for the easy identification from which bag the tuple comes from, so I can iterate through the bag and segregate source and Destination tuples in two Arrays in the UDF. Kindly have a look on the updated pig script and input to the UDF.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a bit large for the comment

```
...
src = FILTER sourcenew BY ID == id1.$0;

finalsrc = FOREACH src GENERATE *, 'Source' as Source:chararray;

dest = FILTER destnew BY ID == id1.$0;

finaldest = FOREACH dest GENERATE *, 'Destination' as Source:chararray;
final =  UNION finalsrc,finaldest ;
A = FOREACH (group final by ID) {
    src = filter final by Source == 'Source';
    dest = filter final by Source == 'Destination';
    GENERATE flatten(PigUDFpck.databag(src, dest));
}
```

In that case UDF will recieve a a tuple containing 2 bag of tuples for which you can do your comparison. Also I'm pretty sure it can be simplified (I mean, you can do this union and group by right after load - just generate a flag for each telling you from if it's source or detination)

Comment: I have got the error,

ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 24, column 17> expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null) 

while executing 

A = FOREACH (group final by ID) {
    src = filter cogroupnew by Source == 'Source';
    dest = filter cogroupnew by Source == 'Destination';
    GENERATE flatten(PigUDFpck.databag(src, dest));
}

may be the way of getting the databag inside UDF is wrong
Please advice me, below is the one I'm  using
public class databag extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {}

Comment: @Vickyster edited. just get the idea and see if it's ok for you.

Comment: Okay @Alexey Thank you I will try it out.!